# Present at school... Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am present at school
> But can't stand pools
> Water tends to scare me
> But croutons appease me
> I frolik in class
> But can't ever pass
> Work can't be for me
> But climbing is my glee
> I crow in all lines
> In each, just one time

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> the letter "c"

I am present at school

> sChool has a c

But can't stand pools

> pools does not

Water tends to scare me

> no c in water

But croutons appease me

> Crouton has a c

I frolic in class

> Class has a c

But can't ever pass

> and pass does not

Work can't be for me

> no c in work

But climbing is my glee

> Climbing has a c

I crow in all lines

> There is a c in every line

In each, just one time

> and just one c per line (in all lines but number 5, as @El-Guest pointed out)

Comment: This feels right, although it appears twice in line 5.

Comment: This is actually correct! I forgot about the c in "frolic" XD